# Want to run maven project in eclipse without WEB-INF\lib folder...how?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

Working on Maven, spring  project in Eclipse Mars using Hibernate  on Tomcat 8. My project is running fine. I need to remove the WEB-INF/lib folder and make the project run? What are the steps to acheive it ?

Comment: Need more detail. Why do you think you need to remove WEB-INF/lib? Did you get an error?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error !!!  Being  an academic project , I have been told to remove the WEB-INF/lib folder that contains a whole host of jar files. Are the references to the same jar files kept anywhere else which might be pointed at using POM maybe ??